# Liquid Transformation: Replace / with

Tags: replace, liquid, azure-logic-apps

I have some trouble by replacing a substring with liquid transformation.
This is my output where I want to replace the forward slash by a dot.

```
"ProductName": "2x19/ display in control room"
```

My code looks like this:

```
    [    
    
    {% for Order_var in content[0].ListOfSmsOrderEntrySales.OrderEntry-Orders.ListOfOrderEntry-LineItems.OrderEntry-LineItems %}
        {
            "Id":"{{Order_var.Id}}",
            "PartNumber":"{{Order_var.PartNumber}}",
            "Product":"{{Order_var.Product}}",
            "ProductDefTypeCode":"{{Order_var.ProductDefTypeCode}}",
            "ProductId":"{{Order_var.ProductId}}",
            "ProductIntegrationId":"{{Order_var.ProductIntegrationId}}",
            "NetPrice":"{{Order_var.NetPrice}}",
            "ProductName":"{{Order_var.Description2 | replace: '/', '.' }}",
        },
    {% endfor %}
    
]
```

I still get the same ouput with no replacement. Any idea? Would be grateful
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `Replace` but not `replace` in your liquid template. The [document](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/replace/) of liquid shows `{{ "Take my protein pills and put my helmet on" | replace: "my", "your" }}`, but according to test, we need to use upper case `Replace` in liquid template.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Never thought about this opportunity. It works fine ;)

Comment: @Lukas_s94 Since your problem was solved, could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my solution as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~